# How does Network Layer behave when client received a unicast DHCP offer?

Tags: ip, dhcp, networking, layer2, layer3

I went through various stack exchange post to understand the concept of DHCP offer when it comes as a unicast to client from the DHCP server.

A server can send a unicast DHCP offer since it knows the host's MAC address. Ok I understood this but what happens at IP layer?  Why host did not dropped the unicast DHCP offer at IP layer?

As per my understanding, an IPv4 host will drop layer-3 traffic delivered to it that is not destined to its IPv4 address, a subscribed IPv4 multicast address, or an IPv4 broadcast address, even if it is delivered via a layer-2 valid mac address frame.

Now since my host does not have any ip address and DHCP offer is not a broadcast address then how come host accepted the unicast DHCP offer? Why host did not dropped the DHCP offer at IP layer?
I hope you got my question. Overall I want to understand what happens to the unicast DHCP offer at IP layer? Can anyone please explain me

Comment: Here's a hint:  when the client sends a DHCPDISCOVER message, what is the source IP of that packet?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A host might not be able to accept a unicast DHCP offer when it doesn't have an address configured. If so it shouldn't claim that it can:

> A client that cannot receive unicast IP datagrams until its protocol
> software has been configured with an IP address SHOULD set the
> BROADCAST bit in the 'flags' field to 1 in any DHCPDISCOVER or
> DHCPREQUEST messages that client sends.  The BROADCAST bit will
> provide a hint to the DHCP server and BOOTP relay agent to broadcast
> any messages to the client on the client's subnet.

Why do hosts accept datagrams when they don't have their IP address configured? The answer that the Python aphorism "practicality beats purity" applies. It saves some unecessary broadcast traffic that sticking rigidly to the rule would generate, so it (often) got implemented that way. Actual networking implementations don't necessarily fit what they teach you in class.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, an IPv4 host will drop layer-3 traffic delivered to it that is not destined to its IPv4 address, a subscribed IPv4 multicast address, or an IPv4 broadcast address, even if it is delivered via a layer-2 valid mac address frame.

That's true for normal operation. While DHCP is in progress on an interface, the stack doesn't care too much about the layer-3 destination field as long as the DHCPOFFER matches a current request. As of [RFC 2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131), "each DHCP server may respond with a DHCPOFFER message". Broadcast is only mandatory for the client for DHCPDISCOVER, DHCPREQUEST and DHCPINFORM messages unless the client already knows the server's address, and for DHCPDECLINE.

What exactly a client regards as acceptable depends on its implementation which isn't on-topic here.